# Why am I getting the error: ERROR: The value 02 is not a valid SAS name. in this simple query

Tags: sas

```
%macro cluster (group);
data count_&group.;
    set enrollment;
where group =&group.;
run;
%mend cluster;
%cluster ('02');
```

I am attempting to parse the data set into groups and name each new table. The macro works if I do not include the data set name. For some reason, SAS does not appear to see the data set name. It sees it as 02 instead of count_02. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Remark: to debug this type of situations, precede your code with `option mprint;`

Your problem is, that you use `'02'` as part of a dataset name. Of course you only want `02`. The solution is to leave the single quotes out of your parameter, i.e. call `%cluster (02);`

However, then you have another problem, because `where group =&group.;` translates to `where group =02;`, where it should be `where group ='02';` or equivalently `where group ="02";` Writing `where group ='&group.';` will not help, because macro variables are not substituted inside single quotes, but they are inside double quotes.

Therefore the solution is

```
    %macro cluster (group);
        data count_&group.;
            set enrollment;
            where group ="&group.";
        run;
    %mend cluster;
    %cluster (02);
```

Comment: I see where my error lies. Adding single quotes around a macro will not work and using quotes around the parameter will not work when attempting to resolve the dataset name. Thank you for the help.

Comment: _Writing where group ='&group.'; will not help, because macro variables are not substituted inside single quotes_

Would you be able to use `%QUOTE` (e.g. `%QUOTE(%'&GROUP%')`?

Answer (score 0):

```
options mprint;
```

would show that the codegen of the macro is

```
data count_'02';
    set enrollment;
where group = '02';
run;
```

and you can see the data set name is improper.

When you pass a macro a parameter that will be used to codegen both a naming part and a value part the typical approach is to base the parameter as simple value (no quotes, etc).  Macro values are implicitly 'as-is' values from the standpoint of generating source code.

So as @Dirk answered your parameter should be passed as `02` instead of `'02'` and the where in the macro changed to `"&group."` so it will codegen `"02"`.

More complexly, you might be supporting code in which the calling code can't be changed  and only the macro can.  In that case the parameter `'02'` must be dequoted in the macro scope when applying it to the data set name.

Example:

```
data have;
  input group $ @@; datalines;
  01 01 02 02 03 03 01 01 01
  02 11 12 13
run;

%macro cluster (group);
data group_%sysfunc(dequote(&group.));  /* dequote the parameter for proper codegen */
  set have;
  where group = &group.;
run;
%mend cluster;

options mprint;

%cluster ('02');   /* parameter passed represents a data step quoted literal */

----- LOG -----
MPRINT(CLUSTER):   data group_02;
MPRINT(CLUSTER):   set have;
MPRINT(CLUSTER):   where group = '02';
MPRINT(CLUSTER):   run;
```